# Buenas tardes, tengo una pregunta sobre los procedimientos de sql

Tags: sql

Mi pregunta es sobre cómo puedo realizar un procedimiento en dónde debo consultar un cliente con su número de identificación

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Hay bastantes diferencias entre los procedimientos almacenados de cada motor, te sugiero que especifiques en tu pregunta que motor de BD estás usando. Por otro lado también sería recomendable que agregues la consulta que ya tienes hecha en esta pregunta.

Comment: Lectura altamente sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Tu pregunta es tan fácil de responder como si yo te preguntara como llego de mi casa al trabajo. Es algo muy sencillo de explicar, pero si no sabes donde está mi casa o mi trabajo se vuelve imposible.

Comment: Provee siempre contexto a tu pregunta. Además, el título debe ser una versión resumida de la misma: sabemos que _tienes una pregunta_, pero el título no describe _cuál es realmente_.

Answer (score 0):

Depende el gestor de base de datos que estés usando.

Primero necesitas saber realizar una consulta, en el caso de querer conocer a un cliente por su identificación, supongo que tienes definido el campo como una primary key

`select * from cliente where id = $tuvalor;`

Ahora crearemos la estructura base de un store procedure > MySql

`Create Defined='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE 'Buscar_Cliente_Por_ID' (in id_pedir int)`

`Begin`

`select * from cliente where id = id_pedir;`

`END`

En SQL Server seria algo asi.

```
Create Procedure Buscar_Cliente_ID

@id_pedir int

AS
Begin

Select * from cliente where id = @id_pedir

END
```

Ya solo para llamarlo usas call en Mysql y Exec en Sql Server

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_. Aguarda a que OP (autor/a de la pregunta) provea más detalles.